# Difference between plotting the same data from a csv file and from array?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I plotted data from CSV file and I converted the same CSV file into NumPy array and plotted the same data. However, I get different graphs, which is confusing and can someone help me if I have made a mistake or I am missing to understand something.

Here is what I have coded and the respective images of the graph.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


csv_file1          = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
columns            = csv_file1.columns
column_name1       = columns[7]
column_name2       = columns[8] 
column_name3       = columns[13]
csv_file1.plot(x=column_name3,y=column_name1,label='width')
csv_file1.plot(x=column_name3,y=column_name2,label = 'normalised width')

data_array = csv_file1.to_numpy()
plt.figure()
plt.plot(data_array[13],data_array[7])
```

Plot using data from the csv file:

[image: Plot using data from the csv file]

Plot using data from the csv file converted to numpy array:

[image: Plot using data from the csv file converted to numpy array]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, they are the same data but when you plot, you choosed wrong index. The CSV is not matter here, you read the CSV file into a DataFrame then using the builtin plot method of `pandas.DataFrame`.

Here is example:

`df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2], "B": [3.0, 4.5]})`

When you plot, using `df.plot(x='A', y='B')`, x will be `[1,2]` and y will be `[3.0, 4.5]`.

Then when convert DataFrame to numpy data using `to_numpy()` method, the data will become:

```
  numpy_data =  array([[1. , 3. ], [2. , 4.5]])
```

So if you using `numpy_data[0]` as x index, it will be `[1., 3.]` which is different to `[1,2]` in above.

To plot the same figure as pandas, you need to choose x, y in numpy as:

`plot(numpy_data[:,0], numpy_data[:,1]`.

**Conclusion:** the plot depends on how you choose the x and y values.

Comment: Ahh, I see the error I have made. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You are probably confusing rows and columns in the numpy array. The convention is `array[row_index,column_index]`, and I think you want to plot column `13` and `7`. Try with:

```
plt.plot(data_array[:, 13],data_array[:, 7])
```